# add a href to a functional submit button

Tags: php, html, form-submit

How can I let the submit button open a link at the same page, at the same time the button submits the input to my php file?
Here is my code as a reference:

```
<form id="input" action="archive.php" method="get">        
    <textarea rows="3" cols="10" name="content" id="content" class="txt" placeholder="blah blah..." required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: and what do you want to happen? open another window/tab with the href?

Comment: @michi Open a link at the same page.

Comment: but by submit, you will open the page specified in the `action` attribute of your `<form>`. please explain, why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `archive.php`, redirect the browser to a new location. You can use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to do that.

```
header('Location: http://www.url.com');
```

This way, all your processing will run in `archive.php` and at the same time, all the user will see is that he arrives at the URL you specified.

Comment: Would also suggest adding the `exit()` function call directly after that to preform the redirect immediately.

Comment: @lampwins Yes, if it's applicable. The processing will not stop when you issue the `header()` call.